# LSTM model giving only one label and accuracy in binary

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, sequential, multilabel-classification

My model giving this answer while training. The accuracy is coming only in binary - 0 or 1. Also, my model is predicting only D label([0 0 0 1]).

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as lstm_cell_layer_call_fn, lstm_cell_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, lstm_cell_1_layer_call_fn, lstm_cell_1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, lstm_cell_2_layer_call_fn while saving (showing 5 of 15). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/drive/MyDrive/SavedModels/OpenfaceRNN_final_7/assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/drive/MyDrive/SavedModels/OpenfaceRNN_final_7/assets
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[[0. 0. 1. 0.]]
(1, 2362, 715)
Epoch 1/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 729ms/step - loss: 1.4395 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 696ms/step - loss: 1.4322 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 705ms/step - loss: 1.4250 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 707ms/step - loss: 1.4178 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 699ms/step - loss: 1.4107 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 703ms/step - loss: 1.4036 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 708ms/step - loss: 1.3965 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 712ms/step - loss: 1.3895 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 700ms/step - loss: 1.3826 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 709ms/step - loss: 1.3756 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 697ms/step - loss: 1.3688 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 698ms/step - loss: 1.3619 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 796ms/step - loss: 1.3551 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 783ms/step - loss: 1.3483 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 727ms/step - loss: 1.3416 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 705ms/step - loss: 1.3349 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 17/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 702ms/step - loss: 1.3282 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 18/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 709ms/step - loss: 1.3215 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 19/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 695ms/step - loss: 1.3149 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 700ms/step - loss: 1.3083 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 21/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 706ms/step - loss: 1.3017 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 22/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 703ms/step - loss: 1.2952 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 23/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 701ms/step - loss: 1.2887 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 24/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 717ms/step - loss: 1.2822 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 25/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 709ms/step - loss: 1.2757 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 26/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 702ms/step - loss: 1.2692 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 27/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 707ms/step - loss: 1.2628 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 28/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 732ms/step - loss: 1.2564 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 29/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 705ms/step - loss: 1.2500 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 30/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 702ms/step - loss: 1.2436 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 31/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 707ms/step - loss: 1.2373 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 32/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 708ms/step - loss: 1.2309 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 33/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 696ms/step - loss: 1.2246 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 34/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 710ms/step - loss: 1.2183 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 35/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 703ms/step - loss: 1.2120 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 36/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 715ms/step - loss: 1.2058 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 37/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 711ms/step - loss: 1.1995 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 38/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 709ms/step - loss: 1.1933 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 39/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 701ms/step - loss: 1.1870 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 40/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 706ms/step - loss: 1.1808 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 41/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 725ms/step - loss: 1.1746 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 42/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 710ms/step - loss: 1.1685 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 43/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 697ms/step - loss: 1.1623 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 44/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 697ms/step - loss: 1.1561 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 45/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 712ms/step - loss: 1.1500 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 46/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 701ms/step - loss: 1.1439 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 47/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 710ms/step - loss: 1.1378 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 48/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 711ms/step - loss: 1.1317 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 49/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 699ms/step - loss: 1.1256 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 50/50
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 704ms/step - loss: 1.1195 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

This is my model:

```
classifier = Sequential()

#input_tensor = Input(shape=(236115, 714))

classifier.add(LSTM(units=1024, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1,input_shape = (2362, 715) ))

classifier.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add((Dropout(0.1)))

classifier.add(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1))

classifier.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add((Dropout(0.1)))

classifier.add(LSTM(units=256, dropout=0.1))

classifier.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add((Dropout(0.1)))


classifier.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add((Dropout(0.1)))

classifier.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))

classifier.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())

classifier.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())

classifier.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())

classifier.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: what is the input_shape to lstm model?

Comment: @Priya 
It's a matrix with 2362 rows here and 715 columns, which are features. I'm changing the rows to get the optimum number, as I'm reducing the rows from 236115 by taking average. So here the input shape is (2362,715). I'm giving a label to a whole video. one matrix is for one video.

Comment: The Lstm model takes a 3D input shape where `input_shape=(Batch_size, time_steps, features)`. You are missing out on the basic working principle of Recurrent Neural Networks.